# How can I remove empty arrays and optimize my POST request?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, web, backend

I have a POST request for Angular,
but it does not work correctly, I cannot understand what the problem is, can you suggest a solution?

The first time I add an element, it just adds an empty array.

The second time, the first element that I clicked on before is added, etc., sometimes empty arrays can still randomly skip

Here is the code:

component:

```
filmFiltered:Film[] = [];

selectFilm(data){
  this.filmFiltered = data;
  console.log(data);
}

likeFilm(){
  this.http.likeFilm(this.filmFiltered).subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(data);
  })
}
```

service:

```
likeFilm(film){
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/favouriteFilm', film)
    }
```

json:

```
{
  "favouriteFilm": [
     [],
    {
      "name": "Film 1",
      "id": 26899533
    },
    {
      "name": "Film2",
      "id": 204457
    },
    [],
    {
      "name": "Film3",
      "id": 128616
    },
    {
      "name": "Film4",
      "id": 173084
    },
    [],
    {
      "name": "Film5",
      "id": 128373
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your JSON structure is a bit off. You have an array consisting of objects (`{ }`) and other empty arrays (`[ ]`). You might want to remove the latter from your JSON. Additionally, you might want to use `array.push()` when selecting  a film. As it stands now, you're reassigning the whole array each item.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a standard loop and delete the empty array;

```js
for(var i = 0; i < favouriteFilm.length; i++){
    if(favouriteFilm[i] === []) favouriteFilm.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user filter method to filter empty array:

```
  likeFilm(film){
     const filteredArray  = film.favouriteFilm.filter( (obj) => !Array.isArray(obj));
     film.favouriteFilm = filteredArray;
     return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/favouriteFilm', film)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned many times, you can filter or remove the elements which are empty array using `isArray()` function.

I would suggest to use `push()` for inserting new film instead of assign it.

```
filmFiltered:Film[] = new Array<Film>();
selectFilm(data){
  this.filmFiltered.push(data);
  console.log(data);
}
```

I think there should not be empty array in the code if you init the array, but if you want to be really sure you can use following code.

```
 likeFilm(){
  this.filmfiltered = [...this.filmFiltered.filter(film => !Array.isArray(film)];
  this.http.likeFilm(this.filmFiltered).subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(data);
  })
```